# Is there a lib to create time intervals to check if given time to hit them in python

Tags: python-3.x, time

Need to set a time interval to be hitted with the given time.

Expect the code to look like this:

```
import datetime
import lib

my_time = datetime.time(hour=7, minute=7, second=7)
my_interval = lib.Interval(from="01:02:03", till="03:02:01)

print(lib.hits_interval(time=my_time, interval=my_interval))
```

I saw code similair enough with pd at [pandas interval](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-pandas-create-a-time-interval-and-use-timestamps-as-the-bounds)

But pandas is operating with timestamp objects, it is unacceptable, the purpose is to process bare time.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `data`/`time`/`datetime` objects directly, they implement the comparison operators:

```
import datetime

my_time = datetime.time(hour=7, minute=7, second=7)
start, end = datetime.time.fromisoformat("01:02:03"), datetime.time.fromisoformat("03:02:01")
print(start <= my_time < end)
```

If you really insist on using a class for this, you can easily create a small `dataclass` based `Interval` object:

```
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Interval:
    start: datetime.time
    end: datetime.time

    @classmethod
    def fromstring(cls, start: str, end: str):
        return cls(datetime.time.fromisoformat(start), datetime.time.fromisoformat(end))

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.start <= item < self.end  # inclusive start, exclusive end


my_time = datetime.time(hour=7, minute=7, second=7)
intervall = Interval.fromstring(start="01:02:03", end="03:02:01")
print(my_time in intervall)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way was to use portion lib:

```
import portion
import datetime

my_interval = portion.open(datetime.time(1, 2, 3), datetime.time(3, 2, 1))
my_time = datetime.time(7, 7, 7)

print(my_interval.contains(my_time))
```